# Sending Ajax request with python return 400

Tags: python, ajax, parsing, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to send ajax request and get json data, but instead I get 400 Bad request

I've tried passing different headers, but it still doesn't work

```py
import requests
import json

headers = {"Host": "www.zalando-prive.it",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0",
           "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
           "Accept-Language": "en-US",
           "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
           "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
           "Referer":"https: //www.zalando-prive.it/campaigns/ZZLPH1"
}

data = {"filter": {},
        "sort": "attractivity",
        "gender": "FEMALE",
        "page": 1}

url = "https://www.zalando-prive.it/api/campaigns/ZZLPH1/articles"
response = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand, while I expect json response

Comment: Try replacing `data=data` with `params=data` and then check. It's unclear what you are trying to do unless you describe the steps to populate json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you provided more info as to I can only guess what you are trying to do.

You can change the `data=data` to `params=data` as suggested in the comments. This will give a response as html however, not a json response (which again, if you provided more information we could debug the issue).

In the html source code, there is a json response, however that needs to be pulled out by some string manipulation and then decoded. Once that is done, you use the `json.loads()` to get that:

```
import requests
import json
from urllib.parse import unquote

headers = {"Host": "www.zalando-prive.it",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0",
           "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
           "Accept-Language": "en-US",
           "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
           "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
           "Referer":"https://www.zalando-prive.it/campaigns/ZZLPH1"
}

data = {"filter": {},
        "sort": "attractivity",
        "gender": "FEMALE",
        "page": 1}

url = "https://www.zalando-prive.it/api/campaigns/ZZLPH1/articles"
response = requests.get(url, params=data, headers=headers)
print(response.text)

jsonStr = response.text
jsonStr = jsonStr.split('data-cms-content="')[-1]
jsonStr = jsonStr.split('" data-reactroot="">')[0]

jsonData = json.loads(unquote(jsonStr))
```